# Visual Studio - Fixing the error "A file of that name is already open"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Occasionally (usually after having updated my .sln file in source control) I get a strange Visual Studio error wherein I'm unable to open some of my files. The files in question show up in the appropriate project, but trying to open them results in an error dialog saying "A file of that name is already open."

This is virtually identical to [Why does it say "Project with that name already opened in the solution"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923235/visual-studio-project-with-that-name-already-opened-in-the-solution), except for files, not projects. The solution given there was does not fix this.

Comment: I noticed sometimes a `devenv.exe` lingers after VS exits, killing it resolved this issue in my particular case (YMMV).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Visual Studio internally maintains a list of currently opened files, to avoid problems caused by opening files more than once. Any number of things (crashes, reboots, updating files in source control outside of VS) can cause this list to become corrupted.

In any case, the problem can be fixed by deleting the hidden `Solution.suo` file which is in the same directory as your `Solution.sln` file. This will cause you to lose your current workspace state (open files, window layout, etc.), but it won't have any other adverse affects on your solution.

This is a hidden file, so to see or delete it you either have to enable viewing hidden files in Explorer or use `del /AH Solution.suo` on the command-line.

Comment: Using VS2008 on Vista, I deleted the Solution.sln.cache file to the same effect.

Comment: Works for VS2010 on Server 2008.

Comment: I don't find the idea of deleting the .suo a good one.  For me just closing VS and open it again solves the problem.

Comment: In some cases this problem is triggered by casing changes on files that are part of a solution. The running document table is mostly strictly case sensitive, while on disk multiple casings may point to the same file. When such files are opened and transformed in Subversion, sometimes the casing changes... causing this error.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the hidden .suo file and edit the .csproj file to remove the lines below:

```
<SccProjectName>Svn</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>Svn</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>Svn</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SubversionScc</SccProvider>
```

Now, reopen the solution to solve the issue.

Comment: This worked for me, had a project which I had switched from Subversion to Git. Removing those lines in the vbproj file resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any linked files in the solution?

Visual Studio has an invariant that only a single file of a given path can be open at one time.  This invariant is hit most often when you have a linked file in your project / solution and attempt to open both the original and one of it's linked references.

Answer (score -1):

Open csproj file of the project and delete following lines:

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

These lines are most probably created due to project is added to visual svn i.e. when project/solution is added to source control project/solution files are updated to include source control integration info and these lines are added which causes issues.

Delete these lines and just reload your project (or solution), this should fix issue.

Comment: VisualSVN does not write these lines into project files.

Comment: you are correct and that is what I had written that it is most probably created by visual svn, though the case is when you add a solution/project into source control, the solution/project file will be updated to include the source control integration info. and during this time above lines are added. - though see the edited answer.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I do not understand. VisualSVN plug-in does not add these lines to project or solution files. I recall that AnkhSVN adds them, though. You could try it yourself with a clean project. :)